Longitude and latitude data from "searching engine" is not drawing a map using R maps/mapdata/ggplot packages
I am trying to draw a map for all province within Egypt using maps and ggplot2 package in R, but I did not find any sub-region (provinces) for Egypt available in the databases of these packages. So, I downloaded coordinates (longitude and latitude) for all provinces in Egypt from google (and other website), and tried to generate the map, but it gave me a totally crumbled picture which is definitely not Egypt' provinces. This made me think that the coordinates from a searching engine (e.g. google) is not like the one used by R. I do understand that R is dealing with coordinates in +ve and negative values, whereas public databases is not. Do I need to convert it somehow to a "R" format ? Could any of you suggest a way around this, especially I did not find Egypt's province long/lat in the databases of R packages?
This is my full code
install.packages(c("ggplot2", "devtools", "dplyr", "stringr"))
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(devtools)
library(ggplot2)

Install some standard map packages.
install.packages(c("maps", "mapdata"))
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

getting world data
mapdata <- map_data("world")

Separate Egypt alone with coordinates
mapdata_Egypt <- subset(mapdata,region == 'Egypt')

Draw Egypt map
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = mapdata_Egypt, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3)


head(mapdata_Egypt, 20) |> dput()

Outcome:
 structure(list(...1 = c("36362", "36363", "36364", "36365", "36366", 
    "36367", "36368", "36369", "36370", "36371", "36372", "36373", 
    "36374", "36375", "36376", "36377", "36378", "36379", "36380", 
    "36381"), long = c(34.1981468200684, 34.2124977111816, 34.2453117370605, 
    34.3285140991211, 34.4009742736816, 34.4899406433105, 34.5177764892578, 
    34.5296859741211, 34.658592224121, 34.7350616455078, 34.7911109924316, 
    34.8698234558105, 34.904296875, 34.8485374450684, 34.7364273071289, 
    34.6171875, 34.4464836120605, 34.4271469116211, 34.3997077941895, 
    34.3185539245605), lat = c(31.3226089477539, 31.2922859191895, 
    31.2083015441895, 30.9950199127197, 30.8278331756592, 30.5962905883789, 
    30.5073738098145, 30.4460468292236, 30.1914539337158, 29.9820308685303, 
    29.8121089935303, 29.5639171600342, 29.4773445129395, 29.43212890625, 
    29.2706050872803, 28.7579097747803, 28.3573226928711, 28.1064929962158, 
    28.0160160064697, 27.8889656066894), group = c(496, 496, 496, 
    496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 496, 
    496, 496, 496, 496), order = c(36362, 36363, 36364, 36365, 36366, 
    36367, 36368, 36369, 36370, 36371, 36372, 36373, 36374, 36375, 
    36376, 36377, 36378, 36379, 36380, 36381), region = c("Egypt", 
    "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", 
    "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", 
    "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


This would be easier to investigate if one knew the content of mapdata_Egypt. Can you edit your question and provide the output of e.g. head(mapdata_Egypt, 20) |> dput()? However, geodata::gadm("Egypt", level = 2, path = tempfile()) is not what you're looking for?

Thanks for providing the info how you created mapdata_Egypt - this makes the head(mapdata_Egypt, 20) |> dput() obsolete. But I don't see any specification about your distorted "coordinates from a search engine" to be used as overlay.
